# No-op merge fails in hg repository converted from SVN

Tags: mercurial

It seems that `hg convert` does not recognise that there should only be one head in this project (the SVN repository I have converted from does not have any branches). I am trying to manually close off the old heads, using [the "No-op merges" technique](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches#No-Op_Merges). However, when I try this, I get:

```
$ hg update -C tip
303 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ hg merge $BRANCH
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

How can something be both a head and a working directory ancestor - after I've checked out tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be both a head and a working directory ancestor because it was previously a branch that was "forked" into the current head, and no changes were ever made after that (so a trivial fork). No great mystery there.

I believe the "no-op merge" technique cannot be used in this case. Use a different technique instead.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to clone another repository from the `tip` so that you don't get all those other heads at all.

In your current repo as you did

```
hg update -C tip
```

and then clone it:

```
hg clone -r tip currentrepo newrepo
```

The new repository should have no inkling of heads other than the `tip`. This is both good and bad depending on how you see it.

Comment: No good for me, because I need to retain the complete repository history.